# Parsing <multi_path literal="not_measured"/> in TinyXML

Tags: c++, tinyxml

How do I parse the following in TinyXML:

```
<multi_path literal="not_measured"/>
```

I am able to easily parse the below line:

```
<hello>1234</hello>
```

The problem is that the first statement is not getting parsed the normal way. Please suggest how to go about this.

Comment: You'll have to be more explicit: what does "is not getting parsed the **normal** way" mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure what youre question is asking but here is a basic format too loop through XML files using tinyXML:

```
/*XML format typically goes like this:
<Value atribute = 'attributeName' >
Text
</value>
*/
TiXmlDocument doc("document.xml");
bool loadOkay = doc.LoadFile(); // Error checking in case file is missing
if(loadOkay)
{
    TiXmlElement *pRoot = doc.RootElement();
    TiXmlElement *element = pRoot->FirstChildElement();
    while(element)
    {
        string value = firstChild->Value(); //Gets the Value
        string attribute = firstChild->Attribute("attribute"); //Gets the attribute
        string text = firstChild->GetText(); //Gets the text
        element = element->NextSiblingElement();
    }
}
else
{
    //Error conditions
}
```

Comment: How do you get the TINYXML2 attribute if you don't know it's name?